# MySQL suffix indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, prefix

searching around trying to find a way to **add index on suffix** of a column I couldn't find a solution.

The only thing for partial index which I found is on prefix of index which is:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

from [12.1.13. CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html)

I also tried other stuff like:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(-10));
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (RIGHT(name,10));
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (SUBSTRING(name,-10));
```

**ALL with same error:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I would like your help!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support indexes on arbitrary expressions. The prefix index is only a quirk, since it's "free" in a typical implementation of B-Tree indexes.

You'll need to add another column to the table, populate it with a trigger, and put index on that.

Comment: Thank you porneL!
Unfortunately, as you said, I will have to create an other column...

Comment: @pan.soultanos: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you've found my answer helpful, please mark it as Accepted.